# How to link to the attachments added from the description of a workitem?

Tags: azure-devops

In VSTS attachment can be uploaded for workitems. Those attachments are displayed in a seperate tab.

[image]

I found no way to reference those attachments from within the description of the workitems.

[image]

So how to do it?

Comment: Just hit the same issue.  You can get it by hitting F12, then Network, then click on the link and see what URL appears here (in Edge you can copy it).  Hard work for something that should be simple!

Comment: This is really fascinating that this is not implemented. Oh, boy! F12 did not work for me.

Comment: 4 years later this still not solved. 
One solution is to use chrome extension like Link Grabber for fast link retrieval  instead of having to delve into Dev Tools

Comment: i can't believe but I miss JIRA; this is too simple a task to involve such heartburn

Answer (score 35):

- drag and drop the attachment to your browsers URL text field
- (optional:) remove the &download=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2 part at the end
- use this URL to create a link in your comment

Comment: This should be the topmost voted answer (_even though some other answers are helpful_), as it gives the least number of steps required to retrieve the URL -- just drag the item to the address bar! I would argue there's hardly any need to edit out the query string from the produced URL.

Comment: A nice answer. One addition: You can drag + drop to your text editor (e.g. Notepad++). URL text field didn't work for me.

Comment: P.S.: For "Test Case Steps" you cannot insert a link directly. But you can create a link via MS Word and copy and paste it into the "Action" or "Expected result" field of ADO.

Comment: I think this is out of date, tried today, didn't work, but there is an option on the file list to get the attachment link

Comment: option (2) works fairly enough.

Answer (score 14):

I did not find another way yet and maybe it is not so logical :). But as workaround you may download an attachment from work item. Then you may copy a download link from your browser download page and use it on description field.

Answer (score 12):

This would appear to be the least "hacky" way, as it relies entirely on the Azure DevOps UI:

1. Go to the attachments list of the work item.
2. While you hover over an attachment, three vertical dots with tooltip "More actions" will be shown: [image: menu button]
   from where you can open a submenu: [image: dropdown menu]
3. In there, click "Copy attachment link".
4. If you paste this link to a text-only context, you will get only the attachment filename, but if you paste it into a rich-text editor with support for links, such as the *Description* field or *Discussion* comments in the work item, **the attachment filename will appear as a clickable link**.

Comment: This does not work any more; the "copy attachment link" option is missing now.

Comment: @orithena: True, it's gone. New "feature" ...

Comment: @orithena: It's back now :)

Comment: It's missing again...

Comment: @Ogreucha: Currently, it's showing again for me.

Comment: Currently working as of march '24 and much quicker than playing with the URL or dev tools

Answer (score 8):

This is amazing that AzureDevops does not have this ability. It's disappointing and makes working with the product so much more difficult. I really cannot imagine how they use this product internally.

You could inspect the attachment url in chromedev tools, then copy the url, the element will look like

```
<div class="grid-cell-contents-container">
<span class="attachment-icon bowtie-icon bowtie-file-content"></span>
<a href="/link.filetype&amp;download=true&amp;api-version=5.0-preview.2" tabindex="-1">filename.filetype</a>
```

Then just remove the `&amp;api-version=5.0-preview.2` part at the end

Come on Microsoft! You're better than this.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround that I found to this which shows a selected text within the comment as clickable and opens the attachment if you click on it is:

1. find and copy the attachment url from browser Developer Tools,
2. select the part of the text in Discussion box that you like to link to the attachment to,
3. paste the attachment url to Address box in Create Link popup. You can get to this by using three dots (...) in Discussion section toolbox (More Tools) and select Create Link which allows you to paste the address.

Comment: Apparently that's the only viable way to do that. And that's insane, given that VSTS/DevOps is an Enterprise platform.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible maybe. Goto attachments and click on list view
[List view of attachments of a workitem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mhD1.png)

Then just left-click on the file of your choice and drag it

Comment: I could not get this to work at all (2021-07 Azure).  I did notice you can drag the attachment to the title of the ticket, which will get you the URL.  But still so hackey..

Answer (score 1):

Select `Copy attachment link` and just paste in the discussion.

[image]

Comment: already this same answer has been proposed, and if you read that, you can see that this option is not available to all, or even consistently

Answer (score 0):

If the attachment is an image and you want to show the image in the Description or Comment field, you can copy the attachment link (see post of O. R. Mapper) and then put an asterix in front of it:

```
![MicrosoftTeams-image.png](https://dev.azure.com/company/guid1/_apis/wit/attachments/guid2?fileName=MicrosoftTeams-image.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling features in the settings
this worked for me.
[image]